# What is wrong with this MySQL insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

The form is ok and it captures all of the information correctly, however, the errors started when I used a function to generate a random string that is used for user activation.

```
function generateActivationString() {
    $randomSalt = '*&(*(JHjhkjnkjn9898';
    $uniqId = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    return md5($randomSalt.$uniqId);
}

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
// $_POST['pass'] = addslashes($_POST['pass']);
$username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
$firstname = addslashes($_POST['firstname']);
$surname = addslashes($_POST['surname']);
// $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['email']));
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['pass']));
$activationString = generateActivationString();
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, surname, email, activation_string) 
VALUES ('".strtolower($username)."', '".$pass."', '".strtolower($firstname)."', '".strtolower($surname)."', '".strtolower($email)."', '".$activationString."')";
```

Here is the echoed insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, surname, email, activation_string) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '')
```

I know it has created a new entry as the auto_increment id row is populated however al of the other fields remain empty.

Here is the code from the generateActivationString() so I know that's working too! - 264361eeb6e75d3934ce249a0d05f2c1

Any suggestions are more than welcome and greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no error, but when I echo out the sql statement all of the fields within the VALUES are blank. Here is the echoed statement: INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, surname, email, activation_string) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '') 
I know it has
Thank you. You have successfully registered. 
here is the code from the generateActivationString() so I know that's working! - 264361eeb6e75d3934ce249a0d05f2c1

Comment: Try to give the output of `echo $insert`. That will show you the actual query (edit it into your question)

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `$insert`, to check that it's a valid query string?

Comment: If the fields seem blank, do they even have a value in the post array? Try `echo print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: probably the if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { return false and all the variables are not set. try var_dump(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) before the if statement to see what's the value.

Comment: try checking whether the code inside the if block is executed or not?.. else the variables will be unset

Comment: [Use prepared statements][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: Maybe `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is `true` and variables aren't getting set? BTW, it's a really bad idea to depend on magic quotes. It's a deprecated feature, the right thing to do is to check for them and undo any changes it does.

Comment: Might it be because you anly assign these values when `!get_magic_quotes_gpc()`?

Comment: Hopefully you're not planning to leave your `randomSalt` hard-coded for your production version. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going strictly by the code above, your variables like `$username`,`$password` etc are in the scope of your `if` block, move them outside of the `if`.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted the if block as @mithunsatheesh said and it worked fine with a few other errors that I sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you send that query anywhere, maybe that's your problem...

Comment: I left that out as I thought that that was a given, the query was executing fine, just the magic_quotes was stopping the activation code form being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear. The biggest problem with your statement is that you are not using prepared statement and taking info directly from the POST parameters. This is a recipe for disaster and how most sites get hacked.

Comment: care to explain disaster scenario?

Comment: Can you explain how I go about checking/validating the user input?